# how to use vars in the command "create partition" with mysql

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures, database-partitioning

I want to create an event that every 15 days executes a procedure. This procedure must to create a new partition. I am doing the following:

```
/*Vars
v_tab  --> logic tables's name
v_year --> year... to use it as part of name
v_fech --> this is used to get the current date  plus 15 days
v_day  --> this is the numbers of days to add to the current date
*/

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CreatePartition;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE CreatePartition (IN v_day INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_year INT;
DECLARE v_fech DATE;
DECLARE v_tab VARCHAR(20);

SET v_year = (select curdate()+0);
SET v_fech = (DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL v_day DAY));
SET v_tab = (select concat('p',v_year));  <--- the char p is because it doesn't accept name with only numbers

ALTER TABLE SystemEvents PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(DeviceReportedTime))(
                PARTITION v_tab VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS("v_fech")),                               
                PARTITION pDefault VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE  
                );
END
//
delimiter ;
```

If I exec this procedure it works, but if I exec it inside an event, it doesn't work

```
call CreatePartition(15);
```

The following doesn't work and I don't know why

```
CREATE EVENT EventPruebas
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 15 DAY
DO
call CreatePartition(15);
```

and I get this error...

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): Not allowed to use NULL value in VALUES LESS THAN near '),
PARTITION p230101 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`TO_DAYS("v_fech")` is not referencing a variable named `v_fech` at all.  It's trying to convert a *literal string* "v_fech" to a number of days.  Of course, that string is not a valid date expression, so TO_DAYS() can only return NULL.

Likewise your reference to v_tab is probably not using the value of the variable v_tab, it's using the actual identifier `v_tab`.

To do what you want to do, you'll have to use dynamic SQL with [PREPARE and EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Something like the following should work (though I have not tested it).

```
PREPARE stmt FROM CONCAT('ALTER TABLE SystemEvents 
    PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(DeviceReportedTime))(
        PARTITION ', v_tab, ' VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS(''', v_fech, ''')),
        PARTITION pDefault VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE  
    )');
EXECUTE stmt;
```